# Batch Create folder by file names with the same name and extension

Tags: file, batch-file, command-line, rename, filenames

I have a lot of jpg files to be moved in a folder with the same name. here my example

```
ABCD, DEFG (1).jpg
ABCD, DEFG (2).jpg
ABCD, DEFG (3).jpg
```

and the files with the same name should be moved in one folder like this.

```
\ABCD, DEFG\ABCD, DEFG (1).jpg
\ABCD, DEFG\ABCD, DEFG (2).jpg
\ABCD, DEFG\ABCD, DEFG (3).jpg
```

is this possible just by using a command prompt?

Comment: Does the folder already exist, or does it need to be created first? Where are all of the files currently located? Are they in the same source directory, or are you going to have to search the entire C: drive to find them?

Comment: no the folder isnt existed yet. it needs to be created first from the filename itself. . all files are in the same source directory and the folder should be also created in the samecsource directory :)

Comment: Please add the extra info to the question by editing tour post; also add your attempts and describe precisely what you have problems with...

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply... :D I already figured out a way to do it.. thanks... GOd bless

Answer (score 0):

It's possible.

Once you recognize a set of files you want to build a directory for and move, use

```
md "ABCD, DEFG"
move "ABCD, DEFG (?).jpg" "ABCD, DEFG"
```

Now, just guessing: You wanted more automation than I built in there. What more?

By the way, the MS documentation for the command prompt commands is very useful. Try

```
md /?
move /?
```

There are lots of sites that'll teach you the various batch file commands. Between those and the documentation, you can figure it out. It's not the greatest programming environment, but it works. And it's everywhere!

Comment: I guess I wanted to have an automation I already have a script but the problem of the script is it makes a folder on each file. not a single folder on eah file with the same string of name.

Comment: for /f %f in ('dir *.jpg /b') do md %~nf & move %f .\%~nf\%~nf.jpg this is the script that I was using but the problem of the script is it creates a folder on each file. not a single folder on a 3  or more files

Comment: I was kinda afraid that would be the ask. I don't know an easy way to do what you want.

Comment: You could make a list of all the files in the directory in a file. (I'd probably do that with cut-and-paste into Notepad; someone else might have an easier way.) There's a sort command that'll sort the lines in the file. You can read through that list to identify all the files you want to receive this treatment. Then, a file like --- start --- for %%f in (%*) do (md %%f  <newline> move ... ) --- end ---, if named a.bat would let you do the work with commands like --- start --- a "ABCD, DEFG" "file2" "file3" ... --- end ---. So, that's an assist, but it's not very automated.

Comment: How better? Well ... probably some other programming environment. Perhaps PowerShell. Or VBScript. Or Perl. Or Node and JavaScript. Or ... whatever else you know.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply... :D I already figured out a way to do it.. thanks... GOd bless

Comment: You're most welcome for the help. And ... you're more than welcome to post your answer and mark it as your preferred answer. Lot's of us may learn something from it! All the best ...